# re-implementation of org.apache.commons.net.io.Util to parse an InputStream

Tags: java, io, inputstream, telnet, apache-commons

`org.apache.commons.net.io.Util` uses `InputStream` which cannot be parsed *live* until the stream terminates.  Is that correct or incorrect?

The [IOUtil](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/net/trunk/src/main/java/examples/util/IOUtil.java) class is a blackbox for me.  It uses `org.apache.commons.net.io.Util` but this is equally opaque.

Specifically, the line `Util.copyStream(remoteInput, localOutput);` of `IOUtil` is intriguing:

> ```
> copyStream
>
> public static final long copyStream(InputStream source,
>               OutputStream dest)
>                              throws CopyStreamException
>
> Same as copyStream(source, dest, DEFAULT_COPY_BUFFER_SIZE);
>
> Throws:
>     CopyStreamException
> ```

How can I read either the original stream or its copy *as it comes in*?  Live telnet connections will have an `InputStream` which does not terminate.  I see no such functionality in the API.

Alternately, re-implementing Apache `examples.util.IOUtil` leads back to the original problem:

```
package weathertelnet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class StreamReader {

    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(StreamReader.class.getName());
    private StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    private InputStream inputStream;

    public StreamReader() {
    }

    public void setInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
        readWrite();
    }

    public void readWrite() throws IOException {
        Thread reader = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                do {
                    try {
                        char ch = (char) inputStream.read();
                        stringBuilder.append(ch);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                    }
                } while (true);  //never stop reading the stream..
            }
        };

        Thread writer = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Util.copyStream(remoteInput, localOutput);
                //somehow write the *live* stream to file *as* it comes in
                //or, use org.apache.commons.net.io.Util to "get the data"
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Either I have a fundamental misunderstanding, or, without re-implementing (or using reflection, maybe) these API's do not allow processing of a *live, unterminated* `InputStream`.

I'm really not inclined to use reflection here, the next stage is, I think, to start breaking down what `org.apache.commons.net.io.Util` does and how it does it, but that's really going down the rabbit hole.  Where does it end?

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/io/Util.html#copyStream%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29

Comment: The problem is how to **concurrently** print and read the InputStream which TelnetClient uses for output.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy a Stream "*live*" but the InputStream will probably block when there is no more input.

You can see the code for `org.apache.commons.net.io.Util#copyStream(...)` [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/net/io/Util.html#line.257)

Comment: that's ok, if there's no more input then there's nothing to read.  when the telnet stream (MUD game) starts up again, it will unblock?  it's the stop and start, live nature of the stream which presents difficulty (I think).  How do you start up the read again?

Comment: The read will block until there is input again.  Just make sure the streaming you are copying flushes (by calling outputStream.flush()) after each message so the reader will see it as soon as possible.

Comment: please do take a look at my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

output first:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ java -jar NetBeansProjects/SSCCE/dist/SSCCE.jar 
print..
makeString..
cannot remove       java.util.NoSuchElementException
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*               Welcome to THE WEATHER UNDERGROUND telnet service!            *
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*                                                                            *
*   National Weather Service information provided by Alden Electronics, Inc. *
*    and updated each minute as reports come in over our data feed.          *
*                                                                            *
*   **Note: If you cannot get past this opening screen, you must use a       *
*   different version of the "telnet" program--some of the ones for IBM      *
*   compatible PC's have a bug that prevents proper connection.              *
*                                                                            *
*           comments: jmasters@wunderground.com                              *
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Press Return to continue:finally -- waiting for more data..





cannot remove       java.util.NoSuchElementException
finally -- waiting for more data..

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*               Welcome to THE WEATHER UNDERGROUND telnet service!            *
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*                                                                            *
*   National Weather Service information provided by Alden Electronics, Inc. *
*    and updated each minute as reports come in over our data feed.          *
*                                                                            *
*   **Note: If you cannot get past this opening screen, you must use a       *
*   different version of the "telnet" program--some of the ones for IBM      *
*   compatible PC's have a bug that prevents proper connection.              *
*                                                                            *
*           comments: jmasters@wunderground.com                              *
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Press Return to continue:



cannot remove       java.util.NoSuchElementException
^Cthufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$
```

then code:

```
thufir@dur:~$ cat NetBeansProjects/SSCCE/src/weathertelnet/Telnet.java 
package weathertelnet;

import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;

public final class Telnet {

    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Telnet.class.getName());
    private TelnetClient telnetClient = new TelnetClient();

    public Telnet() throws SocketException, IOException {
        InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("rainmaker.wunderground.com");
        int port = 3000;
        telnetClient.connect(host, port);

        final InputStream inputStream = telnetClient.getInputStream();
        final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Character> clq = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        Thread print = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                out.println("print..");
                try {
                    char ch = (char) inputStream.read();
                    while (255 > ch && ch >= 0) {
                        clq.add(ch);
                        out.print(ch);
                        ch = (char) inputStream.read();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    out.println("cannot read inputStream:\t" + ex);
                }
            }
        };

        Thread makeString = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                out.println("makeString..");
                do {
                    try {
                        do {
                            char ch = clq.remove();
                            sb.append(ch);
                            // out.println("appended\t" + ch);
                        } while (true);
                    } catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException | ClassCastException e) {
                        out.println("cannot remove\t\t" + e);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
                            out.println("cannot sleep1\t\t" + interruptedException);
                        }
                    } finally {
                        out.println("finally -- waiting for more data..\n\n" + sb + "\n\n\n");
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
                            out.println("cannot sleep1\t\t" + interruptedException);
                        }
                    }
                } while (true);
            }
        };
        print.start();
        makeString.start();
    }

    private void cmd(String cmd) throws IOException {//haven't tested yet..
        byte[] b = cmd.getBytes();
        System.out.println("streamreader has\t\t" + cmd);
        int l = b.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            telnetClient.sendCommand(b[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, IOException {
        new Telnet();
    }
}thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$
```